# Solve the following Dif. Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Dif. Equation is $$(\tan y-2)dx+\left(x\sec^2y+\frac{1}{y}\right)dy=0$$ with the initial condition $y(0)=1$

As it is a non linear equation I think its better to try to do change of variable. Can someone please suggest anyrhing

Comment: This is an "exact" equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$(\tan y-2)dx+(x\sec^2 y+\frac{1}{y})dy=0$$
Change the variables this way:
$$(\tan y-2)dx+x d(\tan y)+\dfrac{dy}{y}=0$$
$$d(x\tan y)-2dx+\dfrac{dy}{y}=0$$
Integrate both sides.

Comment: after integration I think it gives $xtany-2x+lny+c=0$

Comment: Yes thats correct. Dont forget the constant of integration @JalilAhmad

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dx}{dy}+\frac{x\sec^2y}{\tan y -2}=-\frac1{y(\tan y-2)}$$is linear ODE in $x$.